# Video Splitting

Tags: video, video-editor

I am working on a project to create trailers for some footage that we are given, (approx. 2.3 hrs long) and was wondering what was the best way to go through the footage and take out small splits for me to use later. My goal is to harvest as many small segments as possible for each main scene and run them by my colleagues to see which ones best articulate the film. I am working on a Mac and have access to most video editing softwares though I could not find a way to split the footage into segments and save them all as individual files. Is there some trick that I don't know of or a software that expediates the process, since there would be numerous clips (ie. a batch way of saving them all)? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Premiere pro supports the creation of "subclips" which are smaller clips as you describe.

You can then show them to your team from inside premiere or render them to individual videos with the adobe encoder utility.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to the whole stack-overflow system and am learning etiquette here haha, sorry for such a late response